# Why is my view loading but not displaying with segue?

Tags: xcode, segue

I have a bunch of views (5) and a navigation controller the user can go through by pressing buttons that segue to the next view (each view has something the user does and sends data to the next one). My app is connected with a Firebase database, so I'm doing some stuff with that.

Anyway, the view I can't get to work is a TableViewController which works as a checklist, the user must select a certain number of cells, then clicks next and an array is sent through the prepareForSegue to the next view and this view should be display. It isn't. I have some code and some prints in the viewDidLoad that let met know that the view is supposedly loading, just not being displayed.

The screen freezes and the button just remains pressed. It doesn't crash, just stops.

My code has nothing special. It just has a performSegue in the first view and nothing really in the second one.

This is the way they're set up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7DN1.jpg

I've been told the problem is that there are too many push segues or something like that, could it be?

Comment: Are the elements in your view connected to something you deleted?

Comment: No, they aren't.